# MVC2 Html Helpers

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, coding-style, html-helper

I generated a View using VS 2010 functionality.  This auto code generation created this code:

> model.DateDeleted, String.Format("{0:g}", Model.DateDeleted)) %>

I created a custom helper method (extension method) to create a JQuery Calendar control.  This is the syntax for this control on the View:

> 

How can I bind this to the data coming from my Controller?  The Html.TextBoxFor allows a Lambda Expression in its signature.  Here is the signature of the DatePicker code:

public static string DatePicker(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string imageUrl, object date)

I am not sure how to wire the DatePicker with data coming from the Controller.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using your own html helper use `Html.EditorFor` which allows you to use lambda expressions. Now prepare editor template with a jquery date piceker to use it as your editor. It will automaticaly display this template if you will put it in EditorTemplates directory. It's a standard in MVC2 and it really is a good practice.

[This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx) shows how to make it! Enjoy!